# Gtk Sharp - Treeview nodes will not expand sometimes

Tags: expand, gtk#, gtktreeview

Sorry in advance for the vague conditions in which the problem below occurs. It is very intermittent, and I have not pinned down a consistent set of steps that reproduce it yet. (Which is why I'm asking for some general or common things that might cause it)

The application I'm working on consists of `MonoDevelop.Components.Docking` dock frames. There is a tabbed group of panels in one if the frames, and one of them has a `GtkTreeView` in it. Every now and then, the nodes of the Treeview will not expand when clicking on the + button. This does not go away until restarting the application.

However, since I have not been able to consistently reproduce it, I'm kind of at a loss of what to look for/mess with to fix it. So does anyone have any ideas on what might generally cause the nodes to not expand when clicked? Or any better steps I should try in order to reproduce it?

Answer (score 2):

I have found this occurs when a disabled node is in the TreeView. In my case it was a project in the solution pad of MonoDevelop that was set to not build in the current configuration. When I removed the project, all other nodes in the TreeView started working again immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the arrow right/left keys to expand/collapse nodes.

It may be related to a Gtk bug:

https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675835

which was fixed recently:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/gtk?h=gtk-2-24&id=b32a9eb691920f21ad3b9127c833aaba15727c4b